# Rails Mailer: sending emails to a local file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Is there any way to send emails in rails 3 to a local file or so, instead of using an SMTP server? I'd like to test the email's contents without using any kind of SMTP, ideally only in DEV environment.

The best would be a local SMTP or something that allowed me to inspect emails, check email addresses, etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the :test system delivery

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
```

There are also a :file delivery_method

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :file
```

You can define where put all email with file_settings

```
ActionMailer::Base.file_settings = { :location => Rails.root.join('tmp/mail') }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Note: this seems to only be available in Rails 3. (So Rails 2.3 people are out of luck)

Comment: Any idea on how to open these files and see if they are formatted correctly?

Comment: See the other answer for Rails 4. I'm using https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener which is really great!

Comment: this seems not be working on rails 4.2.4, although it is still documented on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html. anybody knows why?

Comment: Is `tmp/mail` supposed to be a file or a directory?

Comment: `tmp/mail` is a directory.  The files in the directory will be named for the mail recipient

Answer (score 6):

There is also the [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem which will save mail to disk and open it in a browser.

Or [mails_viewer](https://github.com/pragmaticly/mails_viewer) which has a Web UI to view the emails instead of opening them in a browser.